# How to close the modal after clicking on the a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal and unable  to close it after clicking in register(i.e a link to #myModal2).
code :

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" id="close"  data-target="#myModal2">Register</a>
   <div id="popup">
   //Contains modal code
   </div>
$("#close).onclick = function () {$('#popup').style.display = "none";}
```

Comment: add a hide class to your div

Comment: It's very simple, just RTM next time before asking https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not closing modal, you show modal with `data-toggle="modal"`.

To close modal, use `data-dismiss`. And put your register `button` into your `modal#popup`.

Or if you want to use Javascript solution:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
   $('#popup').modal('hide');
})
```

[**Official Documentation**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the build in methods provided by bootstrap

```
$('#popup').modal('hide')
```